# String object address possible issue?

Tags: java, string, pointers

Situation: Girlfriend's Java teacher says the following statements are equivalent. At the same time, a Java book recommends the latter form.

```
String a = new String("Hi");

String b = "Hi";
```

Then a.equals(b), and the world is fine.

However, my Java text and C knowledge gravely inform me that since `a==b` as well as `a.equals(b)`, if `a` is changed (Not likely in a `String`, but what if it gets mutated anyhow, as it is probably possible to pass the address somehow that even the JVM won't stop) then `b` will also be changed. As such, it could be dangerous to assume that `b.equals("Hi")`.

Any insight? Is the declaration for `b` really safe, or just a lot lighter on the RAM?

I am not asking about what the difference is. I know that `b` probably references the same object created in `a`.

Comment: Don't worry about RAM. Understand what the difference is between those two declarations.

Comment: hex, I am referring to something that the listed question does not: What about if the String gets mutated in some way? Strings are immutable, but the core String could possibly be overwritten in some way...

Comment: @T.C.: There could also be a cosmic ray pass through your memory and change a bit, better get ECC Memory. /s. But seriously, you don't have to worry about a String becoming changed in memory

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: It's worth noting that string interning is up to the individual compiler (or the JVM?), so `a == b` is not a guaranteed behavior. I seem to remember that the typical implementation currently is to auto-intern strings that have less than 128 characters. After that, `a != b`. It's best just to get used to using .equals() always, and avoid the trouble in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, my Java text and C knowledge gravely inform me that since a==b as well as a.equals(b), if a is changed (Not likely in a String, but what if it gets mutated anyhow, as it is probably possible to pass the address somehow that even the JVM won't stop) then b will also be changed. As such, it could be dangerous to assume that b.equals("Hi").

It is *absolutely* the case that this is safe *because* `String`s cannot be mutated.  It's not possible to "pass the address somehow that even the JVM won't stop" without using JNI or some of the specifically labeled "Unsafe" APIs, in which case you can corrupt everything and all bets are off anyway, which is why those APIs are used only rarely and with extreme care.  (In short, this is not a concern for 99.99% of Java programs.)

If `a == b` and `a` and `b` are references to *mutable* objects, then mutating the object referred to by `a` will absolutely affect `b` as well.  But `String`s aren't mutable, which is why things like interned literals are safe for `String`s.

Answer (score 3):

When you use strings literal string can be [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) ie this:-

```
 String b = "Hi";
```

but when you use `new String("Hi")` you get a new string object.

So

```
String s1 = new String("hi");
String s2 = new String("hi");
System.out.println(s1 == s2);  // False
```

> **Is the declaration for b really safe**

As I said when you use strings literal string can be [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)

> Interning strings makes some string processing tasks more time- or
>   space-efficient at the cost of requiring more time when the string is
>   created or interned. The distinct values are stored in a string intern
>   pool.

Comment: What if the intern gets mutated?

Comment: @T.C.: Strings are immutable. Let's not talk about what we do to interns...

Comment: @StriplingWarrior that was +1 worthy

Comment: @T.C.:- To add to it. Why you want to ask for troubles when things cann be simpler!

Answer (score 0):

The statements are not really equivalent. `a` references another object than b since you asked for it (aka you called `new`). `a==b` will evaluate to `false`.

However `a` equals `b`, and the objects referenced by `a` and `b` cannot be changed.

You cannot ever mutate a String in Java. Trying so (using JNI or whatever) will get you into serious trouble.